# On refresh browser go to last finished step using cookies(java + react)

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-boot, cookies

Ok, so I have simple website which force user to start from last finished step. Whenever user refresh page he needs to call at application initialization to:

```
    REST /user/{id}/step
```

This endpoint will tell where user finished. The problem is I am using http only cookie. So I cannot get this {ID} from cookie in javascript.

At the moment I have added additional cookie(NOT http only) named clientId. So application can get his id from cookie, and call to this particular endpoint.

It is working but I feel that it is kinda not best approach. It has few side effects like taking care of clearing this stupid cookie on logout, etc situations.

What is best practice ? I've been thinking about creating additional endpoint which will be used on every application initialization

```
   REST /user/status
   // I want to be restfull, so I dont want REST user/logged/step
```

which will return setCookie clientId="" or setCookie clientId={ID} whenever user is logged or not, in this case I even don't need to care about clearing cookies on frontend side, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is I am using http only cookie.

So this http only cookie contains what? I presume a user's session? Then why do you need to specify this user ID in the URL if you should be able to get the ID from the session token?

I believe you should just have the following endpoint `REST /user/step` which returns the step number for a **current user** (defined by the session token in the http only cookie) or it returns 401 code (Unauthorised) if the user is not logged in..